# Text to copy cells with formatting into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, copy-paste

I am looking for a way to copy-paste text into Excel, which Excel will recognize as formatted (ie, styled or colored, etc) cells.

On the one hand, Excel recognizes tab-delimited text pasted from the clipboard as cells:

```
    row 1 cell 1     row 1 cell 2
    row 2 cell 1     row 2 cell 2
```

On the other hand, you can *open* an [Excel XML text file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) that includes formatting.

Is it possible to get the simplicity (clipboard copy-paste) of the first approach with the advanced features (formatting) of the second?

---

**Edit**

To clarify: I am looking for a way to copy formatting from a pure text source (like Notepad) into Excel.  I do understand that copying *from* Excel will preserve any formatting that the cells may have, but I am asking if there is any way to to the reverse.

Comment: are you looking for "Paste Special" option. Normally, the "Paste Special" option will help you to keep the source format while copying any data and pasting it to a destination. If this is not, please elaborate a little.

Comment: @vembutech I edited my question ... what I am really asking is whether there is some special sequence of text characters that Excel will recognize as formatting, in the same way that it recognizes the "tab" character as a cell delimiter, and the "newline" character as a row delimiter.

Comment: Don't believe this function exists out of the box. As a workaround you might be able to write some VBA or create some conditional formatting rules to (in effect) create your own markup language.